# What's wrong with getopts or grep here

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, scripting, getopts

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #return codes:
    STATE_OK=0
    STATE_WARNING=1
    STATE_CRITICAL=2
    STATE_UNKNOWN=3

    if [ $# -lt 4 ]
    then
       echo "UNKNOWN: Please, Pass Enough Parameters"
       exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
    fi

    while getopts ":w:c:f:p" opt
    do
     case ${opt} in
       w )
         WARN=${OPTARG}
         ;;
       c )
         CRIT=${OPTARG}
         ;;
       f )
         FILE=${OPTARG}
         ;;
       p )
         PATTERN=${OPTARG}
         ;;
     esac
    done

    COUNT=$(tail -50 ${FILE} | grep -c '${PATTERN}')


    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
            if [ ${COUNT} -gt ${CRIT} ]
            then
                            echo "CRITICAL: The FAIL count is now ${COUNT}"
                            echo $STATE_CRITICAL

            elif [ ${COUNT} -le ${CRIT} -a ${COUNT} -ge ${WARN} ]
                    then
                            echo "WARNING: The FAIL count is now ${COUNT}"
                            echo $STATE_WARNING
            else
                            echo "OK: The FAIL count is now ${COUNT}"
                            echo $STATE_OK
            fi

    else

            echo "CRITICAL: Error while getting the data"
            echo $STATE_CRITICAL
    fi
```

Comment: `grep -c '${PATTERN}'` should be `grep -ce "$PATTERN"`. You forgot to quote many of your variables.

Comment: Please, make your title more concise and try to explain your problem in the body of your question. Also this is not a code review forum, so consider copying only the part of your script that you suspect is at fault (the line with `grep` here seems like a reasonable assumption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `grep` is given as a single-quoted string.  This means that the shell variable `PATTERN` will not have its value expanded within the string.  Instead use `"$PATTERN"`.

Also, as Stéphane Chazelas points out in comments to the question itself, you should double-quote all variable expansions. See "[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)"

You're also inconsistent in your use of the `STATE_` variables.  In one situation, you use `$STATE_UNKNOWN` with `exit` while in the other cases you `echo` their values to standard output.

Also note that diagnostic messages (errors or warnings etc. that are not part of the output of the script if it's running as it should) should ideally be outputted onto the standard error stream. To do that use the redirection `>&2`:

```
printf 'CRITICAL: The FAIL count is now %d\n' "$COUNT" >&2
```

Another thing, which is just a style thing, is that `bash` supports syntax like

```
if (( COUNT <= CRIT )) && (( COUNT > WARN )); then ...; fi
```

(in this case the test against `CRIT` is unnecessary, since it's tested in the previous `if` statement). This arguably makes it easier to type and read the arithmetic comparisons.